# System.Uri class truncates trailing '.' characters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, escaping, uri

If I create a Uri class instance from string that has trailing full stops - '.', they are truncated from the resulting Uri object.

For example in C#:

```
Uri test = new Uri("http://server/folder.../");
test.PathAndQuery;
```

returns "/folder/" instead of "/folder.../".

Escaping "." with "%2E" did not help.

How do I make the Uri class to keep trailing period characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use reflection before your calling code.

```
MethodInfo getSyntax = typeof(UriParser).GetMethod("GetSyntax", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
FieldInfo flagsField = typeof(UriParser).GetField("m_Flags", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if (getSyntax != null && flagsField != null)
{
      foreach (string scheme in new[] { "http", "https" })
      {
          UriParser parser = (UriParser)getSyntax.Invoke(null, new object[] { scheme });
          if (parser != null)
          {
              int flagsValue = (int)flagsField.GetValue(parser);
              // Clear the CanonicalizeAsFilePath attribute
              if ((flagsValue & 0x1000000) != 0)
                 flagsField.SetValue(parser, flagsValue & ~0x1000000);
           }
       }
}

Uri test = new Uri("http://server/folder.../");
Console.WriteLine(test.PathAndQuery);
```

This has been submitted to [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/386695/system-uri-incorrectly-strips-trailing-dots) and the workaround above was posted there.

Comment: It helps. But now I need to preserve trailing '.' in HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery call. I have created another question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804291/asp-net-httprequest-url-truncates-trailing-characters