# Adding fullstops to a URL in C#

Tags: c#, uri

Does anybody know how I could download a URL like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/Apple_Inc.

in C#. The last full stop is always removed. I've tried encoding the . obviously.

Comment: why do you need the full stop, it's not part of the url?

Comment: It is part of the url. Without the full stop a different page is downloaded.

Comment: A quick experiment with `wget` confirms the issue. In C# you ask for the version with the full stop but get the version without.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240203/system-uri-class-truncates-trailing-characters

Answer (score 0):

This works for me....

```
var w = new WebClient();
var downloaded = w.DownloadString(@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/Apple_Inc.");
```

Comment: It doesn't as far as I can see. It removes the last full stop and downloads a different page.